# Bypass Socks for localhost

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, localhost, socks5

I'm in the process of shifting an application from one VM Instance to another within the Azure cloud. The new instance is now hosted behind (multi?) firewalls. For HTTPS I had to configure `-Dhttps.proxyHost=my.https.proxy` and for a required SFTP connection I had to configure `-DsocksProxyHost=my.socks5.proxy` in both cases the required connections seem to be working fine.

However, I am now finding that the application SQL statements (JDBC) are running really really slowly. The MSSQL Server is located on the same server as the Java application, so the connection uses `localhost`. I did some searching and found a post (somewhere) which claimed that the option `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.*|[::1]"` could be used to bypass the socks proxy, even though it is not stated within the documentation, see:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

I've now tested the `nonProxyHosts` and noticed zero performance improvements.

My suspicion is that the issue is being cause by the SQL network traffic being routed out to the Socks proxy and back again, I don't know - maybe the performance issue lies somewhere else?

If socks is the issue, how can I bypass it for localhost connections? If socks isn't the issue, then what can I do to try and find out why the JDBC is soooo slooooow?

Thanks

Comment: "finding that the application SQL statements (JDBC) are running really really slowly" - are the statements running slowly OR it takes a long time to return results? Maybe it is an issue with SQL Server instance. Have you tried running a few queries from outside of your app (e.g. SSMS)?

Comment: Hello Alex, thanks for you comment. The statements were only running slow from the "outside", meaning SSMS was more or less running fine. Either way, I don't know what changes I made, but the performance as improved - it still seems a little slower than before, but it is now acceptable and I'll leave it as is (for now).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what those firewalls are doing it is like shooting with the eyes closed, maybe you can try to disable the firewall for loopback traffic

https://superuser.com/questions/948084/pf-firewall-how-to-disable-all-filtering-on-loopback-interface-except-specific

Comment: Hello Raul, thanks for your feedback. As the performance of the application has improved  (I don't know what I changed), I'll now leave it as is ... however, I will still take a look at the link you provided - for possible future reference, thanks.